# Correlated subquery structured data formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server, correlated-subquery

Im starting out in SQL so be kind, I have created 7 query script that I can run to extract data. I have been told that rather than getting 7 independent files they want all of the data together in one report in a delimited format, so that the MAIN EOC prints one line and all the other queries print with that EOC record, then to the next EOC record as such:

```
TYPE RECORD ACCOUNT NUM  
EOC       1| 000001     | 1stuff | 1stuff |More 1stuff |More 1stuff | even more 1stuff
DIAG      2| 000001     | 2stuff | More 2stuff | even more 2stuff
DIAG      2| 000001     | 2stuff | More 2stuff | even more 2stuff
ADMIN     3| 000001     | 3stuff |More 3stuff | even more 3stuff
ADMIN     3| 000001     | 3stuff |More 3stuff | even more 3stuff
PROC      4| 000001     | 4stuff | 4stuff |More 4stuff | even more 4stuff
EVENTS    5| 000001     | 5stuff | 5stuff |More 5stuff | even more 5stuff
EVENTS    5| 000001     | 5stuff | 5stuff |More 5stuff | even more 5stuff
EOC       1| 000002     | 1stuff | 1stuff |More 1stuff |More 1stuff | even more 1stuff
DIAG      2| 000002     | 2stuff | More 2stuff | even more 2stuff
DIAG      2| 000002     | 2stuff | More 2stuff | even more 2stuff
ADMIN     3| 000002     | 3stuff |More 3stuff | even more 3stuff
ADMIN     3| 000002     | 3stuff |More 3stuff | even more 3stuff
PROC      4| 000002     | 4stuff | 4stuff |More 4stuff | even more 4stuff
EVENTS    5| 000002     | 5stuff | 5stuff |More 5stuff | even more 5stuff
EVENTS    5| 000002     | 5stuff | 5stuff |More 5stuff | even more 5stuff
```

etc ...........

You get the picture.

So how do I take the main EOC query, for example:

```
SELECT
    1Stuff
    ,More1Stuff
    ,EvenMore1Stuff
FROM Somewhere
```

And inject those new queries under each EOC row? I thought about it and realized I cant use a subquery as that will just add more data to the end of the EOC row. Anyone have any ideas on the matter.

Comment: Can you supply sample data and table structure (and perhaps desired results unless the above are your sample results -- a little confusing)?

Comment: @Horaciux EOC = Episode of care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select * from (
<your query 1>
union all
<your query 2>
union all
<your query 3>
...
union all
<your query 7>
)
order by account num, record -- change the column names here
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been crazy busy here. It throws an error at the bottom parenthesis (above order by):
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: I did only 2 records for now and the output comes out as follows:

Comment: Rec_1.AcctNum_2.....MRN_3.......LName_4..FName_5..Date_6
2.....V00000000448..M000000389..TRAIN....RICH.....050519650000
2.....V00000000449..M000000390..TRAIN....ER.......051519420000
3.....V00000000448..M000000389..TRAIN....RICH.....050519650000
3.....V00000000449..M000000390..TRAIN....ER.......051519420000

Comment: But it should look as follows:................................
2.....V00000000448..M000000389..TRAIN....RICH.....050519650000
3.....V00000000448..M000000389..TRAIN....RICH.....050519650000

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the post! It worked. I had to CAST all columns as char and include all the columns that were in query 1 for it to not throw errors. I also had to include 'AS Example' at the ending parenthesis and then ORDER BY Example.Tbl_2, Example.Tbl_1 for it to work. Wonderful! Thanks again.